# Error when Creating SQLite Table Android C#

Tags: c#, android, mysql, sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to create an SQL Table in Anrdoid C# with SQLite and I am receiving an error.

MainActivity.cs Database Code:

```
 public class DbHelper : SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private static String DB_NAME = "NotesDB";
        private static int DB_VER = 1;
        public static String DB_TABLE = "Notes";
        public static String DB_COLUMN = "NoteDesc";

        public DbHelper (Context context):base(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VER)
        {

        }
        public override void OnCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            string query = $"CREATE TABLE {DbHelper.DB_TABLE} (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,{DbHelper.DB_COLUMN} VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL;";
            db.ExecSQL(query);
        }
```

I am receiving the below error.[image: SQLite Error]

**UPDATE 1:**[image: error]

Comment: There is no underscore in `AUTOINCREMENT`.

Comment: I removed the underscore and got the same error

Comment: See the update 1

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` before the semicolon. That's not really the same error; well, the error message, anyway.

Comment: Thank you! Pretty simple fix, don't know how I didnt pick that up -.- I will upvote!

Comment: Thanks, but I've already voted to close as a typo. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

watch the syntax: change `AUTO_INCREMENT` to `AUTOINCREMENT` and put the closing parenthesis:

`String query = "CREATE TABLE {DbHelper.DB_TABLE} (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,{DbHelper.DB_COLUMN} VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL);";`